# Why select json data not working in the mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, version

My query like this :

```
select `information`->'$."full_name"' as `homeroom` 
from `classes`
```

If the query run in my database local, it works. No error

But if the query run in my database server, it does not works. There exist error like this :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."full_name"' as `homeroom` 
from `classes` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

If I run `select version()`,

My version database local : 8.0.15

My version database server : 10.0.38-MariaDB

Seems it does not work because my database server using mariadb

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

I using data type text to infomation field

Comment: *"How can I solve this problem?"* learn from this more reason to make sure that you are using the same database vendor, major and minor version from now on on test/dev and production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON functions weren't added to MariaDB until version 10.2.3. If you can't upgrade you will have to process the data in your application. Note that even in versions that support JSON, they don't support the `->` notation ([reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_extract/)) so you will have to rewrite the query as

```
JSON_EXTRACT(information, '$.full_name')
```

Comment: There exist error : `#1305 - FUNCTION JSON_EXTRACT does not exist`

Comment: @SuccessMan that's what I said, your MariaDB version is not new enough to support them. You will need to upgrade, or process the data in your application.